# Importing and converting multiple files based on criteria in R

Tags: r

Thank you guys in advance for your help, I am faced with the task of importing multiple excels files into R, such files may have a `.csv` or an `.xlsx` extention they all have the same name format which is the word "bookings" followed by a date formart YYYY_MM_DD, like this:

```
bookings_2016_05_23
bookings_2016_12_06
```

After uploading these files I have to write them as `.xlsx` files in a specific directory but I have to replace their names with the last two characters in the name of the file, to illustrate if I upload a file named bookings_2016_05_23, I will have to properly read it whether it is `.xlsx` or `.csv` and then I will have to save it (write) as `23.xlsx` and do that for every file I am trying to accomplish this by using this code:

```
path <- fs::dir_ls(choose.dir())

read_all_files <- function(path){
  path %>% 
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>% 
    map_df(~read_excel(.x, path = path,col_types = "text") %>% mutate(file=path, sheet=.x))
  }
```

which Allows me to import all files and their respective sheets, but this will work if all files were .xlsx and in order to change the name of the file I am trying to uses a `regexs` within the function  set_names() with no luck, also I will be so thankful if you guys could teach me/ reference how to save all files as `.xlsx` separately in a working directory using a for loop. Thank you guys so much I trully do.

Comment: You will need to do this in 2 parts, handle the XLSX and then the CSV files.  You can use something like: `list.files(pattern = "bookings.*csv")` to obtain the list of files to process.  For the CSV files read each file into a data frame and then save data the data frame as an Excel file using the "writexl" or "XLSX" package.

Comment: It seems wasteful and error prone to read xlsx files into R and then write them out again as xlsx files. Why not use a system command to simply rename them after getting their names? Doing a search suggests this part has been asked and answered: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+system+rename+files and I suspect that most of the other parts of this question have also been asked and answered.